# Specifying offset in MediaWiki search

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm querying a MediaWiki instance which we are running. I'm passing the following parameters for the search

api.php?action=opensearch&search=afg&limit=100&format=xml

I didn't see any way to pass the offset as a parameter. Does anybody know how we can pass a offset or if there is an extension which I can use and query it to return results which can be ingested in to my application?

Answer (score 2):

The [opensearch api](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aOpensearch) isn't made for contuing queries, so there is no offset parameter.

However, you can use the [search module](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aSearch) (of action=query) for results like in Special:Search, and there you will have an offset parameter, too.

Comment: I did take a look at it. I don't get the URL of the document in this search. Is there a way to get the URL to the article as part of the search results ? I didn't see anything mentioned in the docs , unless I'm missing something

Comment: You only get pageid and pagetitle, so you will have to build the uri yourself. You can either hardcode that or use meta=siteinfo (in the same query), which will give you the article path variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&prop=info&inprop=url&utf8=&format=json&origin=*&sroffset=0&srlimit=5&srsearch=your_serch_value

this will give you results between 0-5

next page you can set offset to 5 and limit to 5

this will give you results between 5-10, and so on...